# 404 page redirects and SEO

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I hope this is OK to ask here. I am almost ready to upload a new theme to my blog. Which after some serious consideration and research in SEO I have decided to restructure some of the pages, their child pages and to remove some of the categories.

Unfortunately this will result in various 404 results which will be bad for my site.

What I want to do is this:

On the 404 page, before it loads get last parameter of url, so for example: example.com/parent/**child-page-name/**

Then perform a check in wordpress using **get_page_by_title()**.

If the page exists get the page permalink then use php header location to send  301 redirect to the new page.

if not, display 404 page with search options etc..

Is this a good way to handle this? is 301 the correct redirect?

Comment: If you deleted any parent category then for their corresponding child category URL ,you will get 404. Did you do like this?

Comment: I'm not deleting any of the posts, just the pages and categories. I'm just trying to restructure the search crawl better

Comment: Yes I am talking about categories , Did you delete any parent category to restructure it?

Comment: Then what you did to restructure?

Comment: I had some posts in duplicated categories so ive changed them all to one category only. If I need them featured i've created a custom post meta instead, and ive just renamed a few page slugs

Comment: I think rename slug creating issue. can you please share any one example url? which has this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your redirect question, yes the 301 redirect is the correct one to use as it passes on the link equity from the last page.

Rather than using PHP to automatically solve your 404 problem when the new blog is launched, I'd crawl your website first and manually redirect all the old links to the new ones. It's tedious, but it will make sure nothing slips through the cracks that an automated process may otherwise miss.

A good way to do this is to crawl your site as it is at the moment, put all the links into a spreadsheet and put the new urls into the next column. From there you can concatenate the urls into a rewrite rule for the .htaccess file.

To show you what I mean, I have set up a basic sheet you can use to help you out.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1htHq0oeATsfrFJpAxKg0_e5dJqSmJ_idrrH-tudkuq4/edit?usp=sharing

Source: Past experience, Commercial SEO Technician for 2 years